# Given a digit from each of K consecutive integers recover the sequence

Tags: algorithm

A series of `N` consecutive positive integers starting from `X` is written down. Then exactly one digit from each number is chosen and written in the same order. We need to find the smallest `X` for which the series of digits is satisfied.

`N` and the series of digits is given as input. I tried to find some mathematical insight but failed. `N` can be as large as 10^5.

In other words, given and array A of length N containing digits, we need to find an array B of length N containing consecutive positive integers (B[i+1] = B[i] + 1) such that digit A[i] can be found in number B[i] and B[0] is the smallest possible. (No number in B contains leading 0).

For example: if given 9, 2, 1, 2, 2 then smallest X is 19 (19, 20, 21, 22, 23).

Another example: if given 9 8 9 1 0 then such sequence would be 97 98 99 100 101. See that you can find those digits in the given sequence in corresponding number in this series. And 97 is the smallest possible starting number (1097 would also suffice but not the smallest one).

Any hint on how to approach this and this kind of problem would be helpful.

Comment: could you clarify your question with more examples? Is this what your wanting to find? given (1, 3, 10, 4)  would return (10,13,100,14)?

Comment: No. A list of K *consecutive* integers is written down. Then one digit is taken from each number (any of its digits). Then the digits are given in the same order of their parent number. 

For example: if given 9 8 9 1 0 then such sequence would be 97 98 99 100 101. See tha you can find those digits in the given sequence in corresponding number in this series.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe one can do better than brute force?

1. find the smallest number which contains the first digit. 
2. test if that's the case
3. if no, find the next largest number that contains the first digit, goto 2

Comment: Depends on the complexity of this approach. For 10^5 given digits will brute force be fast enough?

Comment: In the second example, it seems that `197` does not suffice.

Comment: Sorry that would be 1097.

Comment: Is it a challenge problem (that is, it's known that a solution exists)? One observation is that the answer is smaller than `10^14`, if `N` is smaller than `10^5`. Might or might not be useful. Still thinking.

Comment: Yes it's a competitive programming problem. The solution is known.

Comment: Could you link the original problem in your post (if the problem is available online)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `O(N^2)`-ish algorithm, which might or might not be good enough, since you didn't link the original problem, so that detailed requirements are unknown.

I will suppose `N = 100000` in the following.

```
For every y in [0, 100000):
    Consider the case that B[0] = 100000 * x + y for some x.
    This will be equivalent to requiring that x contains some of the digits in [0, 10),
    and that x + 1 contains some of the digits in [0, 10),
    from which a smallest x can easily be found (or pre-computed).
    (But the special case x = 0 needs further attention, problem of leading zero.)
Find the maximun of all 100000 * x + y found above, which is the answer.
```

There are further optimizations, with similar idea (e.g. instead of looking at the last five digits, one could look at last three digits, etc.). But I will not post these details now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd manually solve the first example:

> Example: 9, 2, 1, 2, 2

→ The numbers have 5 digits or fewer.

> 9, 2

9 and 2 are different, and not consecutive → they are at different positions:

```
9****, *2***
```

> 9, 2, 1

1 could follow 9, but only if they are in the lowest position (units):

```
****9, 2***0, 2***1  
9****, *2***, **1**
```

> 9, 2, 1, 2

2 could follow 9 and/or 1, but only in the lowest position (units); it could also be in the same position as the earlier 2, but not in the lowest position:

```
****9, 2***0, ****1, ****2  
****9, 2***0, ****1, 2***2  
****9, 2***0, ****1, *2**2  
****9, 2****, *1***, ****2  
9****, *2***, ****1, ****2  
9****, *2***, **1**, *2***  
9****, *2***, **1**, ***2*
```

> 9, 2, 1, 2, 2

2 could be in the same position as one or both of the earlier 2's, but not in the lowest position (units):

```
****9, 2***0, ****1, ****2, 2***3   min. 2 digits   19, 20, 21, 22, 23
****9, 2***0, ****1, ****2, *2**3   min. 3 digits  
****9, 2***0, ****1, 2***2, 2***3   min. 2 digits   19, 20, 21, 22, 23
****9, 2***0, ****1, 2***2, *2**3   min. 3 digits  
****9, 2***0, ****1, *2**2, 2***3   min. 3 digits  
****9, 2***0, ****1, *2***, **2*3   min. 4 digits  
****9, 2***0, *1**1, ****2, 2***3   min. 3 digits  
****9, 2***0, *1**1, ****2, **2*3   min. 4 digits  
9****, *2***, ****1, ****2, *2**3   min. 3 digits  
9****, *2***, ****1, ****2, **2*3   min. 4 digits  
9****, *2***, **1**, *2***, *2***   min. 3 digits  
9****, *2***, **1**, *2***, ***2*   min. 4 digits  
9****, *2***, **1**, ***2*, *2***   min. 4 digits  
9****, *2***, **1**, ***2*, ****2   min. 5 digits
```

---

The key to limiting the number of possibilities to try is of course to follow the most promising (i.e. lowest number of digits) paths first, as we'll do for the second example:

> Example: 9, 8, 9, 1, 0

→ The numbers have 5 digits or fewer.

> 9, 8

8 can only be in a different position from 9:

```
9****, *8***   min. 2 digits
```

> 9, 8, 9

9 could be in the same (not lowest) position as 9, or the same (lowest) position as 8:

```
9****, 98***, 9****   min. 2 digits
9***7, ****8, ****9   min. 2 digits
```

> 9, 8, 9, 1

1 can not be in the same position as any of the other digits:

```
9****, 98***, 9****, **1**   min. 3 digits
9***7, ****8, ****9, *1**0   min. 3 digits
```

> 9, 8, 9, 1, 0

0 can come after one or both of the 9's, but not in the lowest position:

```
9****, 98***, 9****, **1**, 0****   min. 3 digits   97, 98, 99, 100, 101
9***7, ****8, ****9, *1**0, 0***1   min. 3 digits   97, 98, 99, 100, 101
```

---

So a possible algorithm would be:

- For each new digit, check whether it could follow any of the previous digits, and in which positions (1→2 could happen in every position, but 1→2→3 or 1→x→x→4 only in the lowest position; 1→1 can happen in any but the lowest position).
- Check the most promising paths first, i.e. if a new digit can be in the same position as a previous digit.
- If the new digit can't follow any of the previous digits, only then consider an additional position (i.e. the minimum number of digits in the solution increases).
- If you find only large solutions, backtrack and choose a path that looked less promising at the time.

I'm not sure how you'd be able to tell that the smallest solution has been found once you've started backtracking. If you find a solution with *n* digits, then you should probably check all solutions with *n* digits to be certain.

Comment: I don't see where "The numbers have 5 digits or fewer" is mentioned a requirement. The requirement is that `N < 10^5`, and `N` is the sequence length, not the magnitude of the numbers in the sequence.

Comment: @justhalf I mean that if you get a sequence of 5 digits, as in the example, the number is 5 digits long (every digits in its own position) or shorter (if some digits are in the same position).